# Populating <select> element with thousands of data, freezes the webpage. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

**homepage/index.php**

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.id = "survey-form";
var elements = [
       {
           type: "select",
           label: "Send to employee",
           id: "empno",
           options: [] // Options will be populated dynamically
       },
];
elements.forEach(function (element) {
       var wrapper;
       var label = document.createElement("label");
       label.className = "form-label";
       label.textContent = element.label;
       if (element.type === "select") {
           input = document.createElement("select");
           input.id = element.id;
           input.className = "user-input";

           form.appendChild(label);
           form.appendChild(input);
           fetchOptionsUsingWorker(input, element.options);

           $(document).ready(function() {
               $('#' + element.id).select2();
           });
       }
});

function fetchOptionsUsingWorker(selectElement) {
    var worker = new Worker('optionsWorker.js');

    worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        if (e.data.type === 'optionsData') {
            var optionsData = e.data.data;
            populateSelectWithOptions(selectElement, optionsData);
        } else if (e.data.type === 'error') {
            console.error('Error fetching options data:', e.data.message);
        }
    });

    worker.postMessage('fetchOptions');
}

function populateSelectWithOptions(selectElement, optionsData) {
    selectElement.innerHTML = '';
    optionsData.forEach(function (option) {
        var optionElement = document.createElement("option");
        optionElement.value = option;
        optionElement.text = option;
        selectElement.appendChild(optionElement);
     });
}
```

**homepage/optionsWorker.js**

```
function fetchOptionsFromServer() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "../backend.php", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var data;
                if (xhr.responseText === "No data found") {
                    data = ["No data found"];
                } else {
                    data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                }
                resolve(data);
            } else {
                reject(xhr.statusText);
            }
        };
        var data = "input=get_options";
        xhr.send(data);
    });
}

self.addEventListener('message', async function(e) {
    if (e.data === 'fetchOptions') {
        try {
            const optionsData = await fetchOptionsFromServer();
            self.postMessage({ type: 'optionsData', data: optionsData });
        } catch (error) {
            self.postMessage({ type: 'error', message: error });
        }
    }
});
```

As there are thousands of data being fetched from the server, I used webworkers to run the code which fetches the data in the background thread, otherwise the webpage keeps on freezing. But even after using webworkers, it was of no good, as the webpage still freezes. Where am I going wrong? Please guide me.

Comment: Did you try adding all the options in one go, instead of adding every option element to the dom directly. Add them to a fragment, once done add that fragment to the dom.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. It still freezes.

Comment: how many elements on average do you expect to handle?

Comment: The server sends around 70,000 rows of data in an array

Comment: Have you considered using a virtual list instead?

Comment: I just tried adding 70,000 options to a `<select>` and it worked, although it's slow (takes 10 seconds to select an item). So while I would discourage adding that many options to a select, I don't think that's where your problem is. Also, downloading data takes no effort for the client, so a background worker is unnecessary here. I would suggest you strip your code down to a minimal reproducible example so we can try to find where the issue is.

Comment: Have you considered using a more appropriate UI element?   I feel bad for your users if they have to *wade* through 70,000 options in a tiny `<select>`.   For a similar feel, use [tag:select2] with server-side processing/searching/paging.   **Edit**: seems you are using select2 - try using select2's API to get the data.  Converting a (very) large select to select2 will not be quick.

Comment: @freedomn-m can you please reproduce the code, and highlight the part which needs to be modified?

Answer (score 2):

You should use some kind of virtual scrolling, so a usual `<select>` won't work. Basically you need a custom dropdown and add a virtually scrolling list in its popup.

A virtual scrolling with the same row height is implemented quite easily (in this example there's no individual item offset (simplified)):

```js
const arr = Array.from({length:70000}, () => Math.random());

unorderedList.style.height = (arr.length * 32) + 'px';

drawItems();

wrapper.addEventListener('scroll', drawItems);

function drawItems(){
debugger;
  const pos = wrapper.scrollTop;
  const from = pos / 32 | 0;
  const to = from + wrapper.offsetHeight / 32 | 0 + 1;
  unorderedList.innerHTML = arr.slice(from, to).map((item, idx) => `<li>${from + idx + 1}: ${item}</li>`).join('');
  let top = -32;
  [...unorderedList.children].forEach((li, idx) => li.style.top = `${top += 32}px`);
}
```

```css
#wrapper{
  max-height:100vh;
  overflow:auto;
}
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
li{
 position:absolute;
 height:32px;
 line-hieght:32px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<ul id="unorderedList"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Performs well for so many items