Tom Select : Performance with multiple large dropdowns
I need to place several fairly large dropdowns (± 9000 items) on the same web page.
What is the most effective way to do this with Tom Select?

Initialise the 9000 <option>opt1</option>...<option>opt9000</option> in pure HTML then call the JS instruction new TomSelect("#dropdown1",{ //init bloc follows });

or

Create only the <select id="dropdown1"></select> tags in HTML (without creating any <option></option> tags) and then initialise the 9000 options in Javascript only, via a var options = [{id: 'opt1'},...,{id: 'opt9000'}]; (as described in the doc)

or

Through Ajax calls as described in the doc as well?


A dropdown menu with 9000 items sounds like the user interface from hell. Can you not find a way of doing it more elegantly? It drives me crazy having to deal with banks that have 100+ length dropdowns for year of birth  and no way to shortcut scrolling down it!

@MartinBrown I need to select 1..n active employees with a multiple select, that's why I am using Tom Select (for the autocomplete).

use html popover or dialog and populate it with virtual scrolling : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78165092/populating-select-element-with-thousands-of-data-freezes-the-webpage-how-do/78165413#78165413

The first option is slower than the second, because the browser needs to render the HTML element first, and then Tom Select needs to gather the data from the select, prior to initializing the element. Very likely, the UX can be hurt because of this (the first temporary element could be visible for a short period of time).
Also, option 1 would increase the size of the HTML page, which is less likely to be cached by the browser if the visitor request the page multiple times (instead, in the second option, if the data is inside an external JavaScript file, it can be easily cached)
The third option would be the fastest to initialize the element, but it would be much slower to use, as the results need to be fetched as the user types.
Tom Select documentation includes a demo of a dataset of 15000 elements, using the second option. I think it performs ok, in my devices at least: https://tom-select.js.org/examples/performance/
